# SFTP Connection hangs during put operation

Tags: python, sftp, put

I'm attempting to simply push a local file to an FTP destination.
However my script always seems to hang during the "put" operation.

```
filepath = '/home/foo/local.csv'
conn = sftp.Connection(host=HOST, username=USERNAME,
                       port=PORT, password=PASSWORD)
remote_path = 'foo/local.csv'
conn.put(filepath, remote_path)
conn.close()
```

The file successfully gets uploaded to FTP but the control flow gets stuck on the put command. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar issue using Paramiko's SFTP upload. The remote side ends up with an empty file. In my case, this hapens often but not always.. Did you get any further tracking this down?

Comment: I found it useful to modify the channel window size to a larger value than the default depending on what size file you are trying to push via ftp. I was trying to push relatively large files (~200mb) and it seems the window size was too small.